# Trying to learn how to calculate variance by myself, however don't understand this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

```
investment2 = [12, -2, 10, 0, 7, 3]
investment2_mean = sum(investment2)/len(investment2)

print(investment2_mean)

for x in investment2:
    squaring_step = (x-investment2_mean)**2
    variance = sum(squaring_step)
    print(variance)
```

***variance = sum(squaring_step)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable***

Comment: Clearly, `squaring_step` is a float because you calculated it as `(x-investment2_mean)**2`. So why are you trying to calculate the sum of a single float? That makes no sense, and that's why it throws an exception.

Comment: `squaring_step` has just one value in it.The last value. You cannot sum a scalar.

Comment: try doing `sum([(x-investment2_mean)**2 for x in investment2])` although this is not the variance. If looking for the unbiased variance you need to divide by length-1 and if it is the biased one, just divide by length

Answer (score 0):

```
investment2 = [12, -2, 10, 0, 7, 3]
investment2_mean = sum(investment2)/len(investment2)

print(investment2_mean)

squaring_step = [(x-investment2_mean)**2 for x in investment2]
variance = sum(squaring_step)/len(squaring_step)
print(variance)
```

Comment: Can you show a corrected version of the OP's code - with a for loop? And explain why the error was received?

Comment: whats the difference between this and what I posted on the comment? also that variance formula is incorrect

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You were so close:

```
investment2 = [12, -2, 10, 0, 7, 3]
investment2_mean = sum(investment2)/len(investment2)

print(investment2_mean)

my_sum = 0
for x in investment2:
    squaring_step = (x-investment2_mean)**2
    my_sum += squaring_step
variance = my_sum/len(investment2)
print(variance)
```

Comment: Thanks Matina for the answer, I'm still super beginner and it helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will need to create a list to store the values if you want to do so. Or you can directly increment the sum: in case of storing the values:

```
investment2 = [12, -2, 10, 0, 7, 3]
investment2_mean = sum(investment2)/len(investment2)

print(investment2_mean)
squaring_step =[]
for x in investment2:
    squaring_step.append((x-investment2_mean)**2)
variance = sum(squaring_step)/len(squaring_step)
print(variance)
```

You can use a list comprehension as I had noted earlier in the comments:

```
sum([(x-investment2_mean)**2 for x in investment2])/len(investment2)
```

all these are O(2n). You would rather sum directly which is order n as given by @Matina G

Comment: Thank you so much, helped me a lot to understand the concept itself